# pandas draw sum by second

Tags: python, pandas

I have follow  data structure (json)

```
[
{"uid":0,"success":true,"timestamp":10, ....someotherfields },
{"uid":1,"success":true,"timestamp":20, ....someotherfields },
.....
]
```

In test scenario it have  fixed interval of 10, 500 elements success=True than 500 success=False

I need draw success and failure rates on single graph  sum per second
For start I have follow code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open("data.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit="ms")
plot =  df.groupby([df['timestamp'].dt.second]).sum().unstack().plot()

fig = plot.get_figure()

fig.savefig("data.png")
```

Which in my opinion should draw  line parallel  to X with number of data events per second( ~100 in my case )

but i'm getting  follow picture

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

1. i'm wrong in grouping phase or in  ploting?
2. how  to split graphs based on success field to 2 separate lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things going on here. The first is that I believe you want to use the python boolean `True` rather than the javascript `true` in python the latter will be read as a string and when you attempt to group and sum your data this column will be dropped as it is unable to be summed.

Second when you group your data by timestamp you don't need to use `unstack` just specify the column you would like to plot.

```
df.groupby([df['timestamp'].dt.second]).sum().plot(y='success')
```

[image]

Plotting both the True and False value lines is slighty trickier. If you knew the counts would always equal 100 you could just subtract the success from 100 to get the failures, but a safer way is similar to what the original post was doing:

Create some example data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': list(range(0, 10000, 10)), 
                   'uid': list(range(0, 1000))})
df['success'] = np.random.choice([True, False], 1000)
```

Plot the data:

```
df.groupby([df['timestamp'].dt.second, 'success']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).plot()
```

[image]

Comment: I inspect data  and dataframe in debugger, and success is python  True/False
I think json package do this on read

Comment: If the data is stored as a boolean already the above command should work for you, but if not, please comment on what is not working so I can better understand the issue

Comment: Looks like it works now, any ideas how to split True/False to separate   lines?

Comment: Yes, I realize now what you were attempting in the original post, I think you were very close, hopefully this gets you what you need

Comment: Also in this case it is lose TimeStamp  labels, so even  timestamp not start from 0 as in sample,  it will be  0-x integers - just positional index of sum()

Answer (score 1):

For plotting 2 lines: I'm pretty sure pandas `.plot()` function clears any previous plots, so calling `.plot()` twice will only show the second one.

You have 2 choices, then.

1. Pivot the data so on a single line is the counts of success vs failures with a time stamp
2. Access `plotly` directly through the `matplotlib` module.

The first choice would mean transforming your data so a single line looks like:
`timestamp | success_metric | failure_metric`. You can then use a single call of `plot()` to plot both lines.

The second choice involves pulling the relevant data as 2 arrays from the pandas dataframe, importing `matplotlib.plotly`, and plotting them directly.